# Applying for Ireland Visa with UK valid Visa

Tags: uk, ireland, dublin

I intend to visit Ireland during my 15 days vacationing in the UK.

Please, what are my chances of getting the visa?

**I plan to submit the following documents**

1. Hotel Reservation for 2Nights
2. Employment letter, Leave letter, Remuneration review letter, Introduction letter
3. 7 Months Bank Statement **** Two Accounts **** (Since I have 6months printed, I will print for this month making 7 months)
4. 7 Months Payslips
5. 2 land properties doc (Deed and Receipts)
6. Proof of additional income (Invoice, mails)
7. Additional income business profile
8. Tax Certificate (PayE) ****Just like an ID.
9. National ID Card and Work ID
10. Cover Letter (Stating I would like to visit Dublin for 2 nights during my holiday in the UK)

*** Is it compulsory i submit a booked ticket to the UK.

Thank you as I await your response.

Comment: Omo Naija, from what you have provided and the fact that you already acquired a UK visa, your chances are good.

Comment: For clarity, what’s your citizenship and country of residence?

Comment: @TheZealot Gbayii!

Comment: @Traveller Am a Nigerian